# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY error for ionic-plugin-keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I was trying to install ionic-plugin-keyboard with the help from [official Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/). But on the second command i.e. `npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard` I am getting below error:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.12.1
`-- @ionic-native/keyboard@4.3.2
```

Here is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-windows": "^5.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
```

I tried changing `@ionic-native/core` to 4.3.2. But no luck. Please help.

Comment: please try npm recursive-install --save @ionic-native/keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is trying to find the exact `"@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1"` version, but you have the `^3.12.1`.

You can try and change `^3.12.1` to `3.12.1`, delete the `node_modules/` directory, and run `npm install` again to see if that solves your problem.